# Añadir proyecto de mi workspace en eclipse a dinamic web

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo este proyecto en mi workspace:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego he creado dinamic `web project` y he insertado en mi java builth path

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando inicio mi index.jsp que tiene una clase que viene del proyecto "Funcionalidad"

```
          <div id="saludo"><%= Constantes.SALUDO %></div>
```

me sale este error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP:

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [14] en el fichero java generado: [C:\Users\Borja\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JavaProyect\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. clases.Constantes resolves to a package

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 21 en el archivo jsp: /index.jsp
Constantes.SALUDO cannot be resolved to a type
18: 
19: 
20: 
21: <%= Constantes.SALUDO %>
22: 
23: 
24:

**Stacktrace**:

> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:536)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Alguien sabe el motivo.muchas gracias de antemano

MI JSP:

```
       <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
       <%@page import="clases.*"%>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Inicio</title>
     <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
          integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="./js/prueba.js"></script>

     </head>
     <body>

     <!-- MENU -->

    <h1><%=Constantes.SALUDO %></h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Puedes poner index.jsp para ver porque no lo esta reconociendo

Comment: ya está modificado

Comment: y constantes.saludo tiene un metodo de getters y setter?

Comment: no tiene, es public

Comment: Puedes poner el código de la clase para ver bien y no hacer tantas preguntas